# OBJC_EXTERN: what's the purpose?

Tags: objective-c, extern

Hi was reviewing some Objective-C code and found out the following statement:

`OBJC_EXTERN void CLSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);`

What does this mean?
Also, what is supposed to be the syntax of this statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OBJC_EXTERN` is defined in `<objc/objc-api.h>` as

```
#if !defined(OBJC_EXTERN)
#   if defined(__cplusplus)
#       define OBJC_EXTERN extern "C" 
#   else
#       define OBJC_EXTERN extern
#   endif
#endif
```

and therefore prevents "C++ name mangling" even if the above declaration is
included from a C++ source file, as for example explained here:

- [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

For pure C code, you can just remove the `OBJC_EXTERN`, because the `extern`
keyword  is not needed in a function declaration.

---

`NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION` is defined as

```
#define NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(F,A) __attribute__((format(__NSString__, F, A)))
```

and `__attribute__((format(...)))` is a GCC specific extension, also understood
by Clang:

- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#format-string-checking
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

It allows the compiler to check the number and types of the variable argument list
against the format string. For example

```
CLSLog(@"%s", 123);
```

would cause a compiler warning, because `%s` is the placeholder for a string,
but `123` is an integer.

Comment: And there is a syntax for the extern? In this particular case, what is the meaning of the statement?

Comment: Ah, just another C++ crap.

Comment: @pinker: `extern` is necessary to declare (roughly speaking) "global variables". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/1187415 for a complete and perfect explanation. It might be that ancient compilers required the extern keyword also for function prototypes.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. And what it does mean the specific example I posted? Is being NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) being passed as argument to CLSLog call?